# In SwiftUI, where are the control events, i.e. scrollViewDidScroll to detect the bottom of list data

Tags: swift, swiftui

In SwiftUI, does anyone know where are the control events such as scrollViewDidScroll to detect when a user reaches the bottom of a list causing an event to retrieve additional chunks of data? Or is there a new way to do this?

Seems like UIRefreshControl() is not there either...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can to check that the latest element is appeared inside onAppear.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var items = Array(1...30)

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                Text("\(item)")
                .onAppear {
                    if let last == self.items.last {
                        print("last item")
                        self.items += last+1...last+30
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting following error message: "Pattern matching in a condition requires the 'case' keyword" Any solutions?

Comment: @C.Aglar you need to post your code in order me anyone to know why you're getting that error.

Answer (score 29):

Plenty of features are missing from SwiftUI - **it doesn't seem to be possible at the moment**.

But here's a **workaround**.

> TL;DR skip directly at the bottom of the answer

An interesting finding whilst doing some comparisons between `ScrollView` and `List`:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {

        ScrollView {
            ForEach(1...100) { item in
                Text("\(item)")
            }
            Rectangle()
                .onAppear { print("Reached end of scroll view")  }
        }
    }

}
```

I appended a `Rectangle` at the end of 100 `Text` items inside a `ScrollView`, with a `print` in `onDidAppear`.

It fired when the `ScrollView` appeared, even if it showed the first 20 items.

All views inside a Scrollview are rendered immediately, even if they are offscreen.

I tried the same with `List`, and the behaviour is different.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {

        List {
            ForEach(1...100) { item in
                Text("\(item)")
            }
            Rectangle()
                .onAppear { print("Reached end of scroll view")  }
        }
    }

}
```

The `print` gets executed only when the bottom of the `List` is reached!

**So this is a temporary solution, until SwiftUI API gets better**.

> Use a `List` and place a "fake" view at the end of it, and put fetching logic inside `onAppear { }`

Comment: A large thank you! It's a brilliant solution that I would not have thought of. Wish I could give you more than a single "Answered"!

Comment: “This probably means that all views inside a Scrollview are rendered immediately” ... Use view debugger and you’ll see that’s precisely what is going on. This is fairly standard scroll view pattern, where you add everything (from which it can then confirm `contentSize` and present the appropriate scroll indicators).

Comment: This is so clever. SwiftUI really make you thing differently

Comment: You can add a gesture to a `ScrollView` and trigger upon dragging. For example, `.gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: length).onEnded{ _ in print"Done!" })` which might be useful here.

Comment: @MoFlo  I tried your suggestion with a List, and the event never seemed to fire as I scrolled the list up & down. Guessing the List struct suppresses events like this some way. Is there a way to see this event regardless?

Comment: if you need solution which works with List or ScrollView see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60563668/swiftui-async-data-fetch/60569935#60569935

Comment: many many Thank you from bottom of my heart
cheers

Answer (score 10):

In case you need more precise info on how for the scrollView or list has been scrolled, you could use the following extension as a workaround:

```
extension View {

    func onFrameChange(_ frameHandler: @escaping (CGRect)->(), 
                    enabled isEnabled: Bool = true) -> some View {

        guard isEnabled else { return AnyView(self) }

        return AnyView(self.background(GeometryReader { (geometry: GeometryProxy) in

            Color.clear.beforeReturn {

                frameHandler(geometry.frame(in: .global))
            }
        }))
    }

    private func beforeReturn(_ onBeforeReturn: ()->()) -> Self {
        onBeforeReturn()
        return self
    }
}
```

The way you can leverage the changed frame like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {

        ScrollView {

            ForEach(0..<100) { number in

                Text("\(number)").onFrameChange({ (frame) in

                    print("Origin is now \(frame.origin)")

                }, enabled: number == 0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `onFrameChange` closure will be called while scrolling. Using a different color than clear might result in better performance.

edit: I've improved the code a little bit by getting the frame outside of the `beforeReturn` closure. This helps in the cases where the geometryProxy is not available within that closure.

Comment: Great to use as an analogue of the UIKit delegate method scrollViewDidScroll.

Answer (score 3):

I tried the answer for this question and was getting the error `Pattern matching in a condition requires the 'case' keyword` like @C.Aglar .

I changed the code to check if the item that appears is the last of the list, it'll print/execute the clause. This condition will be true once you scroll and reach the last element of the list.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var items = Array(1...30)

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                Text("\(item)")
                .onAppear {
                    if item == self.items.last {
                        print("last item")
                        fetchStuff()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The OnAppear workaround works fine on a LazyVStack nested inside of a ScrollView, e.g.:

```
ScrollView {
   LazyVStack (alignment: .leading) {
      TextField("comida", text: $controller.searchedText)
      
      switch controller.dataStatus {
         case DataRequestStatus.notYetRequested:
            typeSomethingView
         case DataRequestStatus.done:
            bunchOfItems
         case DataRequestStatus.waiting:
            loadingView
         case DataRequestStatus.error:
            errorView
      }
      
      bottomInvisibleView
         .onAppear {
            controller.loadNextPage()
         }
   }
   .padding()
}
```

The LazyVStack is, well, lazy, and so only create the bottom when it's almost on the screen

Answer (score 2):

I've extracted the `LazyVStack` plus invisible view in a view modifier for `ScrollView` that can be used like:

```swift
ScrollView {
  Text("Some long long text")
}.onScrolledToBottom {
  ...
}
```

The implementation:

```swift
extension ScrollView {
    func onScrolledToBottom(perform action: @escaping() -> Void) -> some View {
        return ScrollView<LazyVStack> {
            LazyVStack {
                self.content
                Rectangle().size(.zero).onAppear {
                    action()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```