# Why SwiftUI loads the items in the reverse order?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a streaming app consists of multiple channels and each channel has DVRs.On the main page, all channels are displayed in rows according to their categories. And When the user clicks on a channel item it goes to a detailed page that contains DVRs in a horizontally scrollable row. All channels and DVR items have images and I am loading images from URL by using URLImage (https://github.com/dmytro-anokhin/url-image) library. The issue is when I run the app, the channel images load from right bottom to top left which is from the last item to the first item. When I click on a channel and navigate to a detailed screen, the images for the DVRs start loading from right to left, which is from the last item to the first item. And this creates a problem because the channels have too many DVR data and it takes 5 seconds to load all images. It would be great if it started to load the images from the first item so even if it takes 5 seconds the user would not realize and get effected.

I do not understand why it acts this way. Is there a solution to fix this issue? How can I force it to start loading from the first item to the last one. Here is my code to display DVRs in:

```
    ForEach(1..<chan.getDVR().count, id: \.self){index in

       Button(action:
       {
           self.str = self.chan.getDVR()[index].getHlsStreamURL()
           self.refresh = false
           self.ind = index

       }) {
            dvrItem(DVRItem: self.chan.getDVR()[index])
                .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                .padding(.trailing,3)
                .cornerRadius(7)

       }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())             
    }
```

and the dvrItem:

```
struct dvrItem: View {

        var DVRItem: dvr

        var body: some View {
             VStack( alignment: .leading) {
                URLImage(URL(string: DVRItem.getLogoUrlHD().replacingOccurrences(of: "http", with: "https", options: .literal, range: nil))!,  placeholder: { _ in Image("nologo").resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill).clipped() } ){
                    proxy in
                    proxy.image
                        .resizable()                     // Make image resizable
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill) // Fill the frame
                        .clipped()                       // Clip overlaping parts
                }
                .frame(width: 198, height: 114)
                .cornerRadius(7)
                .padding(.leading, 10)
                .padding(.top, 5)
                Text(self.DVRItem.getName())
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .padding(.leading, 5)
                    .padding(.trailing, 5)

                Text(self.DVRItem.getDescription())
                    .foregroundColor(Color(red: 80.0/150, green: 80.0/150, blue: 80.0/150))
                    .lineLimit(nil)
                    .padding(.leading, 5)
                    .padding(.trailing, 5)
                Spacer()
                    .frame(height: 5)

            }
        }
    }

    struct dvrItem_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            dvrItem(DVRItem: channels[0].getDVR()[0])
        }
    }
```

What am I going wrong? By the way I tried to load only the first 10 DVR items like `ForEach(1..<10, id: \.self){index in` but it gave run time error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying many things I resolved the issue by using URLImage Library's option.

URLImages has a delay option that you can use to delay the process of image loading. And usage is as follows:

```
    URLImage(URL(string: DVRItem.getLogoUrlHD().replacingOccurrences(of: "http", with: "https", options: .literal, range: nil))!, delay: 0.25,  placeholder: { _ in Image("nologo").resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill).clipped() } ){
        proxy in
        proxy.image
            .resizable()                     // Make image resizable
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill) // Fill the frame
            .clipped()                       // Clip overlaping parts
    }
```

I updated my DVRItem and added a new variable called index:

```
    var ind: Int
```

And used that variable to load the first 5 elements without delay, load the next 15 elements with 0.15 delay and load the rest of the elements with 0.25 delay. That way it immediately loads the first 5 elements and then loads the rest. My final code is like this:

```
struct dvrItem: View {

    var DVRItem: dvr
    var ind: Int

    var body: some View {
         VStack( alignment: .leading) {
            URLImage(URL(string: DVRItem.getLogoUrlHD().replacingOccurrences(of: "http", with: "https", options: .literal, range: nil))!, delay: (self.ind < 5) ? 0 : (self.ind < 20 ? 0.15 : 0.25),  placeholder: { _ in Image("nologo").resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill).clipped() } ){
                proxy in
                proxy.image
                    .resizable()                     // Make image resizable
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill) // Fill the frame
                    .clipped()                       // Clip overlaping parts
            }
            .frame(width: 198, height: 114)
            .cornerRadius(7)
            .padding(.leading, 10)
            .padding(.top, 5)
            Text(self.DVRItem.getName())
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .padding(.leading, 5)
                .padding(.trailing, 5)

            Text(self.DVRItem.getDescription())
                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 80.0/150, green: 80.0/150, blue: 80.0/150))
                .lineLimit(nil)
                .padding(.leading, 5)
                .padding(.trailing, 5)
            Spacer()
                .frame(height: 5)

        }
    }
}

struct dvrItem_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        dvrItem(DVRItem: channels[0].getDVR()[0], ind: 0)
    }
}
```

And I call the DVRItem as follows and assign the ind with index values:

```
ForEach(1..<chan.getDVR().count, id: \.self){index in

   Button(action:
   {
       self.str = self.chan.getDVR()[index].getHlsStreamURL()
       self.refresh = false
       self.ind = index

   }) {
        dvrItem(DVRItem: self.chan.getDVR()[index], ind: index)
            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
            .padding(.trailing,3)
            .cornerRadius(7)

   }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())             
}
```

I still don't know why it starts loading from the last item but this solved my problems. I tried similar solutions like in this post [In SwiftUI, where are the control events, i.e. scrollViewDidScroll to detect the bottom of list data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56602089/in-swiftui-where-are-the-control-events-i-e-scrollviewdidscroll-to-detect-the) but they don't work for horizontal scrolls.